# Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + z/n)^n$ does NOT converge uniformly on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

We're currently analyzing the convergence of function sequences.

I need to prove
$$
    \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{z}{n}\right)^n
$$

is not uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{C}$. Can I just use the equivalence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$ and show this is not uniformly convergent to $e^z$? Or is there a way of showing it using the supremum norm?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The point-wise limit is $e^{z}$. If the convergence is uniform then there exists $n_0$ such that $|(1+\frac z n)^{n} -e^{z}| <1$ for all $z$ whenever $n \geq n_0$. Put $z=n$ to get $|2^{n}-e^{n}| <1$ for al $n \geq n_0$. However, $|2^{n}-e^{n}|=e^{n} |1-(\frac 2  e)^{n}| \to \infty$ since $(\frac 2  e)^{n} \to 0$. This contradiction shows that the convergence is not uniform.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the convergence were uniform. Then, for $\epsilon = 1$, there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that
$$\left|\left(1 + \dfrac{z}{n}\right)^n - e^z\right| < 1$$
for all $n \ge N$ and $z \in \Bbb C.$ (Note that we have used the fact that the sequence converges pointwise to $z\mapsto e^z$.)

In particular, for $z = n$ in the above, we must have the inequality
$$e^n - 2^n < 1$$
for all $n \ge N$.

However, note that $e^n - 2^n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ and so, we can find $N_0 \ge N$ such that
$$e^{N_0} - 2^{N_0} > 1.$$

This gives us a contradiction.